# Consuming an API which has a two types which are the same but have different names. How can I reuse my code?

Tags: c#, .net, generics, types, .net-3.5

I'm consuming a web service which returns two types which are exactly the same but are called two different things (yeah, great API I know...). One type's called `SearchKMQueryResponse`, the other is called `TopSolutionsKMQueryResponse`. I am mapping the output from these types into my own model classes and have to use two methods which take different parameter types, but return the same type. The two API types inherit the `object` type, so I cannot pass in a base type as a parameter. They do not expose interfaces via the API so I'm screwed there too.

So is there an elegant solution to stop repeating myself in the below code? ...

**EDIT: I'm using .Net v3.5 for this solution.**

```
      public static KmSearchResponse Map(SearchKMQueryResponse response)
    {
        if (response == null)
        {
            return null;
        }
        else
        {
            var myResponse = new KmSearchResponse()
            {
                CountTotal = long.Parse(response.model.instance.resultlist.resultlist[0].Value),
                Message = response.message,
                Status = (MyProject.Model.StatusType)response.status,
            };

            for (var startID = 2; startID < (myResponse.CountTotal * 5); startID += 5)
            {
                myResponse.Results.Add(
                    KmSearchResponseResultsMapper.Map(
                    response.model.instance.resultlist.resultlist, startID)
                    );
            }

            myResponse.Count = myResponse.Results.Count;

            return myResponse;
        }
    }

    public static KmSearchResponse Map(TopSolutionsKMQueryResponse response)
    {
        if (response == null)
        {
            return null;
        }
        else
        {
            var myResponse = new KmSearchResponse()
            {
                CountTotal = long.Parse(response.model.instance.resultlist.resultlist[0].Value),
                Message = response.message,
                Status = (MyProject.Model.StatusType)response.status,
            };

            for (var startID = 2; startID < (myResponse.CountTotal * 5); startID += 5)
            {
                myResponse.Results.Add(
                    KmSearchResponseResultsMapper.Map(
                    response.model.instance.resultlist.resultlist, startID)
                    );
            }

            myResponse.Count = myResponse.Results.Count;

            return myResponse;
        }
    }
```

Comment: If that type is very small you can write a wrapper easily

Comment: Do the SearchKMQueryResponse  and TopSolutionsKMQueryResponse  are some autogenerated classes on your client side?

Comment: Never mind, you already got the answer that was in my head from: CodeCaster

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I assume `SearchKMQueryResponse` and `TopSolutionsKMQueryResponse` are generated WCF data contracts. Those are generated as partial classes, so you can write another partial for them where you apply an interface:

```
IQueryResponse
{
    SomeModel model { get; set; }
    SomeMessage message { get; set; }
    SomeStatus status { get; set; }
}

public partial class SearchKMQueryResponse : IQueryResponse { }
public partial class TopSolutionsKMQueryResponse : IQueryResponse { }
```

Now you can change your mapper to accept an interface as input:

```
KmSearchResponse Map(IQueryResponse response)
```

Comment: You just blew my mind sir! I had to verify it and it works like a charm.

Comment: @CodeCaster, What a beautifully simple and elegant solution. I had to mess with my namespaces before I got it right for it to work, but it does. Thanks for the response and the example code.

Answer (score 1):

My gut reaction is to say "leave it as is" - you don't control the API, so there may come a day when the different classes contain different properties. If that day ever comes, you'll have to unpick the code where you've 'merged' the two together.

You have also not specified whether the types of the properties within each of the API's response classes are the same, or whether they too are separate classes using the same naming system. If they *are* different, then no form of base class or interface is going to help.

I would create two extra constructors for KmSearchResponse, one accepting a parameter of type SearchKMQueryResponse and the other accepting a parameter of type TopSolutionsKMQueryResponse. Each constructor can then extract out the fields it needs.

Comment: You do have fair points with your warnings, +1 for that. OP though stated: _"two types which are exactly the same"_. :)

Answer (score 0):

you could use the dynamic keyword, but you wont get any intellisense.

http://www.hanselman.com/blog/C4AndTheDynamicKeywordWhirlwindTourAroundNET4AndVisualStudio2010Beta1.aspx

EDIT: Alternatively you could write a strongly typed wrapper for each class and share a base type

Comment: We're stuck with .Net v3.5 I'm afraid.